# Looping through fields to validate with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

Is there a way to do this with `jQuery`?

Here is setup:

```
<input type='checkbox' class='sk1' />   <input type='text' class='skill1' />
<input type='checkbox' class='sk2' />   <input type='text' class='skill2' />
<input type='checkbox' class='sk3' />   <input type='text' class='skill3' />

<input type="button" onclick="validate();" />
```

*Important:  The input field to the right of checkbox is associated with checkbox.*

When button is clicked, I want this check:  Each `checkbox` that is **checked**, can **not** have an empty `input` field to the right of it.  When it finds one, it will stop and throw an `alert`.

Looking around, I see I will need to probably uses `regex` and perhaps the jQuery`.each`.

Pseudo code:

```
for each checkbox class^=sk[number]
    check if input[type=text] that has a class with skill[same number as above]
    if empty, alert,
       Otherwise, continue checking other boxes
```

(Sidenote: Writing that pseudo makes me wonder if there is a better naming convention I can use so that I don't have to extract specific numbers out of these.)

(another note:  When an checkbox is NOT checked, the text field is disabled; I have this working)

Can someone give me some guidence on this?

Comment: it would be more simple to help you if you post relevant HTML code, not pseudo (useless) code...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have real code to give you since I had no idea where to start on this one. So I was trying to give you a logical order to what I was trying to do.

Comment: I was talking about the HTML code, to check its structure and see if checkboxes and inputs are direct siblings or not

Comment: Oh sorry about that; the html is being put together by php and is rather messy.  So I was trying to simplify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just loop the checkboxes and check the `next` text element:

```
$(":checkbox:checked").each(function() {
    if (!$(this).next(":text").val().length) {
        alert("You must put in text!");
        return false; //bail out of the loop, return true to skip to the next iteration
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uvQ6C/

Comment: That is so simple.  I am not to familiar with the `.next` command so that explains why I made this so difficult sounding.

Comment: Got to love simplicity :)

Comment: I will mark you correct as time expires... I made one slight change to get it to work, `if ($(this).next(":text").val("")) {`

Comment: That will set the value to be nothing! And will always pass the `if` -- the `.length` is there a boolean check as `0` is falsy

Comment: When I did it your way, it said length was undefined?  to be exact `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: Hmm..well, with your way you would want `($(this).next(":text").val() == "")`

Comment: @KickingLettuce -- I've also made a fiddle to show the above code working: http://jsfiddle.net/uvQ6C/

Comment: works for me!  I also have to add an `&&` to that to make sure the textbox is enabled. And it's done.  I've got that part though, thanks again!